# Why dpes this code print "False"? Why doesn't it print "True"?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

When I run this code it prints `False`. it's not clear to me

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        float f = 0.1;
        if (f == 0.1)
            printf("True");
        else
            printf("False");
    }
```

I expect this code to print out `True` instead of `False`

Comment: generally speaking you should use `double` not `float`

Comment: Note that `0.1` cannot be exactly represented in either a `float` or a `double` variable. But if you stick to the same floating point type, there can be equality of these imprecise values. My compiler warns me that the `double` value `0.1` is being truncated to `float`.

Comment: Typically the nearest representable `float` value to `0.1` is `0.100000001490116119384765625`, while the nearest `double` value is `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. Those are the values you're comparing.

Answer (score 5):

`0.1` is a `double` constant. In `float f = 0.1;`, the `double` value is implicit converted to `float`. The `float` and `double` types have different precisions, so the conversion incurs a small rounding error. In consequence, the `float` value stored in `f` is not equal to the `double` value of `0.1`.

If you change `0.1` to `0.1f` in both places it appears, the program will print “True”.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer. But, please can you explain to me the semantics behind `0.1f`?

Comment: @محمودخالد: I suggest that you read about [suffixes in floating constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant#Suffixes). The `f` suffix simply means that the floating constant is of type `float` instead of `double`.